# telnet open can not connect on a specific Centos server

Tags: centos, telnet

i am using below command in the server but it cant connect to given ip and port, I tried to telnet from another locations and it works fine. Only in my server it cant connect.

```
telnet
open 151.XXX.235.47 9001

Trying 151.XXX.235.47... 
telnet: connect to address 151.XXX.235.47: Connection timed out
```

I tried to open debuggin in telnet by using

```
telnet> toggle debug
Will turn on socket level debugging.
```

But telnet still gives same output

```
Trying 151.XXX.235.47... 
telnet: connect to address 151.XXX.235.47: Connection timed out
```

What should i check in the server to get an idea why it cant connect?

EDIT :

It seems there was a problem with my firewall, we reinstalled it and problem fixed. Thanks for help

Comment: iptables, static routes and/or default gateways if not in the same segment

Comment: What do you mean by same segment?

Comment: Given a /24 mask, your segment is the whole 255 address space. You don't give specifics, so we can only guess. Anyway, you have an answer below that is probably right, did you try it?

Comment: yes, i tried it but still server cant access. What specifications can i list here to give more information?

Comment: `ping $server"`, `traceroute $server` on $server `tcpdump port 9001` during a connection attempt, `iptables -L INPUT -vn` as requested below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to check is your firewall. By default CentOS won't have port 9001 open and unless you've taken steps to open it it's most likely your problem. Take a look at the output of

```
iptables -L INPUT -vn
```

and see if there is a rult that would allow traffic on port 9001. If there isn't or there isn't an obvious rule to allow the traffic then try

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT
```

If this doesn't fix your problem then it could be any number of other things like for example another firewall between you and the destination that is blocking the port etc...

Comment: i have the rule added like this : pkts : 0 bytes : 0 target : ACCEPT prot : tcp opt : -- in : * out : * source : 0.0.0.0/0 destination : 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:9001 . Shouldnt destination be my ip? if so how can i modify it?

Comment: @user2314575: 0.0.0.0/0 means any address ...

Comment: After i run "service iptables stop" on the server, It was able to access, but i dont think stopping iptables is good idea.

Comment: @user2314575: edit your question and include the output of `iptables -L -v -n`